# Migration of SSIS packages from 2008 to 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012, ssis, ssis-2012

We are trying to migrate all SSIS packages from 2008 R2 to 2012 version. I have changed config file to native client 11 and also made changes to the individual connection managers.

But, I am still getting this errors.

Can anyone please help me in solving these errors:

[Connection manager "xxxxxxxx"] Error: The requested OLE DB provider SQLNCLI10.1 is not registered. If the 64-bit driver is not installed, run the package in 32-bit mode. Error code: 0x00000000.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Service Components"  Hresult: 0x80040154  Description: "Class not registered".

[Connection manager "xxxxxxx"] Error: Consider changing the PROVIDER in the connection string to SQLNCLI11 or visit http://www.microsoft.com/downloads to find and install support for SQLNCLI10.1.

[Log provider "SSIS log provider for SQL Server"] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "xxxxxxx" failed with error code 0xC0209303.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: Looks like you have a reference to SQLNCLI10.1 in your connection managers that have not been corrected. If you're only fixing this via changing config files... it might be that as part of package validation, before it applies the configuration, it is attempting to use that database resource and the error is generated. If that's the case, then you need to fix all the CMs across all the files as part of your migration efforts. I would have thought the wizard would have done that for you. Oh, also check that there isn't an expression that has the provider hard coded.

Comment: Yes, the provider has been hard coded in the config file...So I have made necessary changes in the config file.

Comment: Even in the connection managers, I have made necessary changes. But I am not able to make any changes in the data sources because those are being used by other packages.

Comment: Do you think this is because of any driver installation problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

IF you go right click on your project name and under the debugging tab you can change the Run64BitRuntime to False and that may fix that problem.